# Rate of Heat Flow Across the Surface of a Sphere

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]
This is cal 3-4 and I assume I need a surface integral of some sort. But, all this time I have been working with field vectors and fluid. Therefore, I don't even know what formula to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the surface integral

$$\iint_S \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}$$

where $\vec{F}=-7\nabla u$ and $\vec{S}$ is the sphere of the star.

You can parameterize the sphere as $<2\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta},2\sin{\phi} \sin{\theta}, 2\cos{\phi}>$.

Without parameterizing,

$$\vec{F}=7<\frac{x}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3}, \frac{y}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3},\frac{z}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3}>$$

$$\vec{n}=<\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},>$$

The dot product of these two gives you a constant, and $\iint_S dS$ is just $4\pi R^2$.

Comment: It doesn't give me the correct answer, I keep getting 896pi/3, and I'm sure my steps are right because I just did a similar problem, could it be your formula?

Comment: The answer is 28pi if that helps

Comment: @ShetBox: I can get 28pi using that formula. Can you write how you did it? Also, for this problem, you do not even have to parameterized the sphere.

Comment: F = [+7x(x^2+y^2+z^2),7y(x^2+y^2+z^2), 7z(x^2+y^2+z^2)]
parametrization r = <2sinϕcosθ,2sinϕsinθ,2cosϕ>
n = rtheta X rphi 
then integral (F dot n) DA where DA is just dϕdθ with bounds 0<θ<2pi and 0<θ<pi

Comment: Your $F$ should be $\frac{7x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}, .....$. I think the problem is easier without parameterizing. I'll add that. @ShetBox